# iPad Calendar Style Flip?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Can anyone give me any advice on setting up the ability for a user to flip from screen to screen on the iPad. Similar to how you can flip from day to day in the default Calendar application.

Can I take advantage of anything that is built in? or does this need to be custom built.

Any advice or starting tips/hints would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering, [UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) allowed me to achieve this.